# Drupal Access Denied issue after admin login

Tags: php, drupal

I am getting access denied issue when I try login to Drupal admin panel.

Login was successful but showing access denied error.

I solve it previously by truncating sessions table. But now even after truncating sessions table also it is not working.

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: Can you add to your post your apache vhost configuration ? Do you use wamp ? or native apache on linux ? or nginx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just Commented the following line in Config File (Host File). It started Working.

```
fastcgi_hide_header Set-Cookie;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear sessions table in database
2. Clear cache in database
3. Clear all cookies in browser
4. Clear all browser cache

Comment: I tired but its not working...I cleared cache and sessions table

Comment: try to remove your cookies, it helped me

Comment: - try logging in at /user/login page.

Comment: The checklist did help. Specifically: - remove any cookie domain setting from settings.php (uncomment them).

Comment: Also see the .httaccess needed to be changes

Answer (score 0):

It is probable an issue with a cookie.

If you are using chrome

(1) go to : chrome://settings/cookies.

(2) paste the link of your website.

(3) delete the session cookie.

(4) Try access your site again and Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem of access denied when I tried to move my code from production to staging. I had to clear the cache and this helped me.

1. Goto `sitename/user/login and login` using your credentials.

   The link to the website may be broken.
2. Goto `sitename/admin/config/development/performance` and clear the cache
3. Now try to login again.

If you are using chrome, then clear the cache in too.

Comment: use drush. `drush cc`

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings.php file and check that $cookie_domain is set to the correct domain name.

This worked for me.